# Why am i getting Input Mismatch Error (Java)

Tags: java

So far i have this.

```
  import java.util.*;
  public class Moviesol{
  public static void main (String[] args){
    Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
    Movie[] m = new Movie[3];
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
        String name =sc.nextLine();

        String company =sc.nextLine();

        String genre =sc.nextLine();

        Long budget =sc.nextLong();
        m[i] = new Movie(name, company, genre, budget);
    }

    String ip = sc.nextLine();

    MovieByGenre(m , ip);


}
public static void MovieByGenre(Movie[] m, String ip ){
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
        if(((m[i].getgenre()).equals(ip))&& (m[i].getbudget()>=80000000)){

                System.out.println("High Budget Movie");}
        else if(((m[i].getgenre()).equals(ip))&& (m[i].getbudget()<=80000000)){ 
                System.out.println("Low Budget Movie");
        }
    }
}
}
```

This is the other class

```
class Movie {
private String name;
private String company;
private String genre;
private Long budget;
public Movie(String name, String company, String genre, Long budget){
    this.name=name;
    this.company=company;
    this.genre=genre;
    this.budget=budget;
}
public String getgenre(){
    return genre;
}
public Long getbudget(){
    return budget;
        }
}
```

I am using getter methods to grab info from other class. The program takes

'name' of String type

'Company' of string type

'genre' of string type

'budget' of long type.

i need to match genre with the 'ip' String, if it matches, budget is compared , and prints accordingly

My input

```
asd
asd
asd asd
90000000000
asd
asd
asd asd
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:939)
at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1594)
at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextLong(Scanner.java:2373)
at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextLong(Scanner.java:2328)
at Moviesol.main(Moviesol.java:13)
```

Please help!!!

Comment: well function MovieByGenre has the same conditions in if and else if or I just can't find any difference.

Comment: use debugger to check if that condition satisfies or not

Comment: Update your original post with the new content or if it is a different question then close/delete this and post a new question.

Comment: I'm trying to take genre input with space, and input 'ip' of type String with spaces too, and match them(i took 'asd asd' as genre input) , but I can't make out why i am getting those InputMismatchError!!

Comment: `at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextLong(Scanner.java:2373)` This is telling you that it is trying to find a long, and it can't. I would guess that after the first .nextLong(), the cursor is on that same line, so when you read the second `name`, you are actually reading the empty space at the end of the 90000000000. Then when you are reading company you are getting `asd` then genre = `asd` then you are looking for a long again, but the cursor is in front of the `asd asd`. Instead of getting the nextLong, read it as a string and parse it.

Comment: Thank you. Will let you know if this fixes it.

Comment: It looks like you read three movies before checking on genre.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import java.util.*;
public class Moviesol{
public static void main (String[] args){
Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
Movie[] m = new Movie[3];
for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
    String name =sc.nextLine();

    String company =sc.nextLine();

    String genre =sc.nextLine();

    String strBudget =sc.nextLine();
    Long budget = null;
    try {
        budget = Long.parseLong(strBudget);
    } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
        // what happens if they didn't enter a number
    }
    m[i] = new Movie(name, company, genre, budget);
}

String ip = sc.nextLine();

MovieByGenre(m , ip);
```

}

Comment: this fixed this. Thank you !! :)

Answer (score 0):

The exception means that the input read from the file does not fir into the object you want to store it. For example scanner.nextInt() thows that exception if the next element is "abcd".

Your related code is:

```
        String name =sc.nextLine();
        String company =sc.nextLine();
        String genre =sc.nextLine();
        Long budget =sc.nextLong();
```

So for each movie you have to enter 3 lines of text and one long integer number.

`asd asd` is only one line, and surely not a number.